# Difference in seconds between two TDateTime variables

Tags: delphi

Looking for a code sample that returns the difference in seconds between two TDateTime values.    Specifically, I am trying to compare two TDateTime values and if greater than a second threshold it will run a specific method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 52):

Try the [`SecondsBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween) function which is part of the DateUtils unit.

Sample of use

```
SecondsBetween(Now, IncSecond(Now,10))
```

Will return 10

Comment: As an interesting aside, the function may return something other than 10 since Now is called twice!

Answer (score 26):

Call [`SecondsBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween) from the `DateUtils` unit. For example:

```
Assert(SecondsBetween(MyAnswer, RRUZsAnswer)=7)
```

Comment: Were you guys continuously refreshing the question list? Or did you have software tracking?

Comment: Probably the former